# Xamarin app build error with Android 12.0 (S)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Here's the error :

System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate Attribute.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XAGJS7009: System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate attribute.
      at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.AddAttributeSkipNotify (System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute a) [0x00030] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XElement.cs:1929 
      at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify (System.Object content) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XContainer.cs:486 
      at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Add (System.Object content) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XContainer.cs:140 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.AddLauncherIntentElements (System.Xml.Linq.XElement activity) [0x0004e] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument+<>c__DisplayClass99_0.<ActivityFromTypeDefinition>b__1 (Android.App.ActivityAttribute aa, System.Xml.Linq.XElement element) [0x00008] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.ToElement[TAttribute] (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type, System.String name, System.Func`2[T,TResult] parser, System.Func`2[T,TResult] toElement, System.Action`2[T1,T2] update) [0x0007d] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.ActivityFromTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type, System.String name, System.Int32 targetSdkVersion) [0x00043] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.Merge (Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper log, Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionCache cache, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] subclasses, System.String applicationClass, System.Boolean embed, System.String bundledWearApplicationName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] mergedManifestDocuments) [0x004c2] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x00766] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.RunTask () [0x0000e] in <256050d9b61b4848876345a052636c75>:0 
      at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:17  (XAGJS7009) (AppName.UI.Droid)
```

It only appears when I target android 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove the explicit exported flag for the activity, that I have added before because of the error it was giving me when targeting Android SDK 11.0.99

I have only removed the splash screen exported flag and the app runs normally

Here is the issue information: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6463